# MySql ENUM no funciona al editar tabla

Tags: mysql, enum

en MySql creé una tabla con diez columnas y uno de sus datos se llama nivel_id definido como un Tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL.
El problema que tengo es que al querer editarlo para reemplazar Tinyint por ENUM, al momento de guardar los cambios no saltan errores, pero tampoco se guardaron los cambios. La tabla sigue con sus datos originales con la que fue creada.
Sólo para probar, edité Tinyint por un Int y al guardar los cambios ahí sí los veo y MySql me indica que los cambios fueron guardados sin problemas. Así que supongo que hay algo que anda mal con ENUM. Alguna idea de cuál podría ser el problema?
Saludos!

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, conviene que [mejores la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) incluyendo el código que utilizas y el texto del error que recibes para que otros puedan reproducir y entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Si vas a utilizar `ENUM` es necesario que también indique los valores que acepta. Seguramente no has indicado TODOS y por esto da error.

Comment: No se agrega solucionado (eso se ve cuando la respuesta figura en verde) ni se pone la respuesta en la pregunta... autoresponderte esta muy bien... agrega la respuesta en el campo respuesta....